# Java printf performance

Tags: java

Does Java call the `(g)libc` function `printf` with the parameters or does Java do the replacing itself, which is slow I assume?

So when I do `System.out.printf( ... );`, does Java interpret the `%s`, `%d` and call `.replace("%d", something)` or does it just call the native `printf()` c function, pass it just through to the C/C++ native code?

Comment: It does not call the C library.

Comment: Why do you assume "Java doing the replacing itself" is slow?

Comment: “which is slow I assume” —you assume incorrectly.  Java benchmarking is a complex undertaking, but you should still look into doing it, correctly, before assuming anything.  I think the difference will be much smaller than you’re expecting.

Comment: I mean slow, as in doing all of the replacing within Java instead of native printing where it all is already implemented. Reinventing the wheel, again, for the sake of being proprietary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the code for [printf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) is done in Java.

Most of the magic happens in the [java.util.Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) class.

```
System.out.printf(String format, Object ... args)
```

will eventually call:

```
formatter.format(Locale.getDefault(), format, args);
```

See [Formatter#format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#format(java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) as well.

Comment: What a bummer. libc has already all of that implemented, for almost any type of I/O. As I said above, reinventing the wheel.